# PHP MySQL Count rows from INNER JOIN - GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do here, is I want to output the count of the `id` and `user_id` columns from `items`, by users which have the rank `1`.
Let's say there's 8 rows in `items` which have a `base_item` of **400**, and these 8 rows, where 2 rows of them has a `user_id` of **4** and the existing left has a `user_id` of **6** 
The output should then be:
`$countItems = 8` and `$countUsers = 2`.

```
$stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(*),`user_id` FROM `items` 
    INNER JOIN `users`
    ON `users`.`id` = `items`.`user_id`
    WHERE `base_item` = :i AND `rank` = 1 
    GROUP BY `user_id`,`items`.`id`
");
$data = array(':i' => '400'); // item_id in `values` table
$stmt->execute($data);
if($inv = $stmt->fetch($db->FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $countItems = $inv['id'];
   $countUsers = $inv['user_id'];
}
```

I have tried several methods, but I still keep getting output `2` and `2` even though the results should be `8` and `2`.

**Table Info for `values`:**
[image]

**Table Info for `items`:**
[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry, I made the question more clear.

Comment: See previous comment

Comment: I've read it, still doesn't solve my issue, or making me able to rewrite the question more clear.

Comment: And so on, I still don't know what I should search for on Stackoverflow, to get a question with an answer that could solve my issue too.

Comment: and how does one copy paste from an image to recreate your problem?

Comment: @e4c5 what you complaining for? You asked for table structure, and I included it.

Comment: Obviously by joining 2 tables together, instead of 2 sqls with a foreach loop as I did?

Comment: and like I said, how does one copy paste from your screenshots? Please do read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please do find a button in MySQL Workbench which SHOW CREATE TABLEM

Comment: If you want me to create a SQL Fiddle, please just write that, instead of just saying "show me table"

Answer (score 2):

First of all you never want to fetchAll() and discard the data just to count the number of rows. There is a better way.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `base_item` = :item AND `user_id` = :uid
```

Secondly, you should try to avoid a nested loop whenever possible because nested loops don't scale very well. And the solution is to use a join or a subquery. You haven't posted your table structures, so this query is untested.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), user_id FROM `items` INNER JOIN users 
 ON users.id = items.user_id
 WHERE `base_item` = :item and rank =1 GROUP BY user_id
```

One query instead of two, a lot less number of lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is it, but I still need only to have the sql queried by users with a rank of 1.

Comment: Should I just add `AND users.rank = :rank` before `GROUP BY`?

Comment: since it's such a simple query, you can try it directly in your sql console substituing a value for :item

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't count the `id` so I cannot output, how many items of that there is, and the count for `user_id` just counts the user_id it self, and not how many columns containing user_ids.

Comment: If you understand hehe

Comment: please post your tables using SHOW CREATE TABLE and please put a few lines of sample data

Comment: One query instead of two? No, it's one query instead of 1+n !!

Comment: hello @Strawberry haven't bumped into you for a while. Your input is always appreciated.

Comment: Hey @e4c5 I have updated the Q, with an image of my table.

Comment: Edit, I made the instructions of what I would want way more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're replacing `$smst` withing the foreach loop.

Use other variable name, for example:

```
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $user) {
   $stmt2 = $conn->pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`,`user_id` FROM `items` WHERE `base_item` = :item AND `user_id` = :uid");
   $stmt2->bindParam(':item', $cmsval['item_id'], $db->PARAM_INT);
   $stmt2->bindParam(':uid', $user['id'], $db->PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I'm just replacing `$stmt` which is not used anymore, after the `foreach` loop has been executed. Anyway, it didn't make any difference. Thanks for your effort tho.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I actually had to do, was remove `GROUP BY` and add `COUNT DISTINCT` instead, like following:

```
$stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) as `uid`, 
          COUNT(`items`.`id`) as `id` 
   FROM `items` 
   INNER JOIN `users`
   ON `users`.`id` = `items`.`user_id`
   WHERE `base_item` = :i AND `rank` = 1
");
$stmt->bindParam(':i', $cmsval['item_id'], $db->PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
if($inv = $stmt->fetch($db->FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $countItems = $inv['id'];
    $countUsers = $inv['uid'];
}
```